# how to write this complex mysql query in Dynamo db

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

How can I modify this query to dynamo db query, i am not able to find the examples on aggregate functions and also date operations in dynamo db..

```
SELECT DATE(`date`) AS day ,SUM(`power`) AS power 
  FROM `ogm` 
  WHERE `id`!=0 
   AND DATE(`date`)>=DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 31 DAY GROUP BY day;
```

Comment: DynamoDB != MySql, it's different structure and you can't write MySql-like queries there

Comment: But how is it possible to get the similar output that i am getting from mysql tables.

Answer (score 0):

Use DynamoDB client and [scan](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.DynamoDb.DynamoDbClient.html#_scan) operation to run complex query.

Something like this **not tested**:

```
$client->scan([
    'TableName' => 'omg',
    'ScanFilter' => [
        'id' => [
            'AttributeValueList' => [
                'S' => '0',
            ],
            'ComparisonOperator' => 'NE',
        ],
        'date' => [
            'AttributeValueList' => [
                'S' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-31 days')),
            ],
            'ComparisonOperator' => 'GE',
        ],
    ],
    'ConditionalOperator' => 'AND'
]);
```

[`ComparisonOperator`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.DynamoDb.Enum.ComparisonOperator.html) values list.

Keep in mind that this query will return only up to 1mb of data, you have to re-loop it. And don't even think about pagination :D

Comment: Its giving .....Uncaught exception: Found 2 errors while validating the input provided for the Scan operation:
[ScanFilter][id][AttributeValueList][S] must be an associative array. Found string(1) "0"
[ScanFilter][date][AttributeValueList][S] must be an associative array. Found string(10) "2016-09-04"  Not able to handle this error .